# Expressing a theorem about idempotent substitutions

Tags: agda

I'm working in a simple library containing definitions and properties about substitutions for simple types. I'm using the following encoding for types:

```
data Ty (n : Nat) : Set where
   var : Fin n -> Ty n
   con : Ty n
   app : Ty n -> Ty n -> Ty n
```

so, since variables are represented as finite sets, substitutions are just vectors:

```
Subst : Nat -> Nat -> Set 
Subst n m = Vec (Ty m) n
```

The complete development is in the following paste: http://lpaste.net/107751

Using this encoding, I have defined several lemmas about such substitutions, but I do not know how to define a theorem that specifies that substitutions are idempotent. I believe that I must use some property like weakening in order to express this, but I can't figure out how.

Could someone give any directions or clues?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Substitutions are not generally idempotent, it's no surprise you can't prove they are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Substitutions that produce expressions over fresh variables are indeed idempotent.  But in order to express this theorem, you have to consider your substitution `Subst n m` as one operating on the joint variable set `Subst (n + m) (n + m)`.  Here is a variant that uses arbitrary variable sets `A` and `B` instead of `Fin n` and `Fin m`.

```
open import Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality using (_≡_; refl)

-- Disjoint union.

data _+_ (A B : Set) : Set where
  left  : A → A + B
  right : B → A + B

-- A set of variable names can be any type.

Names = Set

-- Simple expressions over a set of names.

data Tm (A : Names) : Set where
  var : A → Tm A
  app : Tm A → Tm A → Tm A

-- Substitute all variables from set A by terms over a name set B.

Subst : Names → Names → Set
Subst A B = A → Tm B

subst : ∀{A B} → Subst A B → Tm A → Tm B
subst σ (var x)   = σ x
subst σ (app t u) = app (subst σ t) (subst σ u)

-- Rename all variables from set A to names from set B.

Rename : Names → Names → Set
Rename A B = A → B

rename : ∀{A B} → Rename A B → Tm A → Tm B
rename σ (var x)   = var (σ x)
rename σ (app t u) = app (rename σ t) (rename σ u)

-- In order to speak about idempotency of substitutions whose domain A
-- is disjoint from the variable set B used in the range, we have to promote
-- them to work on the union A+B of variable sets.

-- The promoted substitution is the identity on B,
-- and the original substitution on A, but with the result transferred from B to A + B.

promote : ∀{A B} → Subst A B → Subst (A + B) (A + B)
promote σ (left  x) = rename right (σ x)
promote σ (right x) = var (right x)

module _ {A B : Set} (σ₀ : Subst A B) where

  -- Now assume a promoted substitution.

  σ = promote σ₀

  -- A promoted substitution has no effect on terms with variables only in B.

  lemma : ∀ t → subst σ (rename right t) ≡ rename right t
  lemma (var x) = refl
  lemma (app t u) rewrite lemma t | lemma u = refl

  -- Hence, it is idempotent.

  idempotency : ∀ x → subst σ (σ x) ≡ σ x
  idempotency (right x) = refl
  idempotency (left  x) = lemma (σ₀ x)
```